# What does symmetrize mean? (imposing multifreedom constraints to stiffness matrix)

Tags: finite-element, constraints, block-decomposition

I have a small FEM implementation program. And I want to add imposing multifreedom constraints (MFC) feature to it. The theory of master-slave method is given [here](http://www.colorado.edu/engineering/cas/courses.d/IFEM.d/IFEM.Ch08.d/IFEM.Ch08.pdf) (page 10 for general case).

Stiffness matrix (static truss) is given in a rearranged block form:

$
\begin{bmatrix}
       K_{uu} & K_{um} & K_{us} \\
       K^{T}_{um} & K_{mm} & K_{ms} \\
       K^{T}_{us} & K^{T}_{ms} & K_{ss}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
       u_{u}\\
       u_{m}\\
       u_{s}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
       f_{u}\\
       f_{m}\\
       f_{s}
\end{bmatrix}
$

The form of the general constraints equations is a linear combination of DOFs:

$A_{m}u_{m} + A_{s}u_{s} = g_{A}$

We can find $u_{s}$ from this as follows:

$u_{s} = -A^{-1}_{s}A_{m}u_{m} + A^{-1}_{s}g_{A} = Tu_{m} + g$

Then I should "insert ($u_{s}$) into the partitioned stiffness matrix and **symmetrize**" to obtain:

$
\begin{bmatrix}
       K_{uu} & K_{um}+K_{us}T \\
       symm & K_{mm}+T^{T}K^{T}_{ms}+K_{ms}T+T^{T}K_{ss}T
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
       u_{u}\\
       u_{m}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
       f_{u}-K_{us}g\\
       f_{m}-K_{ms}g
\end{bmatrix}
$

I wanted to reproduce the last step but couldn't get the result. What is "to symmetrize"?

Comment: Looking at the source, I see a different set of equations in the PDF.

Comment: My mistake. I have an old version of this book and it's a bit different. Now $K_{ss}$ and other $K$'s with $s$ subscript don't disappear which is closer to my results but i still can't reproduce it. I found Wikipedia article on symmetrizing but this is for tensors and I'm not sure how to apply it to my case.

Comment: @danny_23 isn't it just $\frac{1}{2}(K^T+K)$? Assuming $K_{\mu\mu}$ are already symmetric I would assume $symm=(K_{um}+K_{us}T)^T$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the old trick...
(first seen [here](http://www.citeulike.org/user/miccoli/article/9471000) as far as I know.)

For brevity I will introduce $Ku = f$ with
\begin{align}
K &= \begin{bmatrix}
       K_{uu} & K_{um} & K_{us} \\
       K^{T}_{um} & K_{mm} & K_{ms} \\
       K^{T}_{us} & K^{T}_{ms} & K_{ss}
\end{bmatrix}
&
u &= \begin{bmatrix}
       u_{u}\\
       u_{m}\\
       u_{s}
\end{bmatrix}
&
f = \begin{bmatrix}
       f_{u}\\
       f_{m}\\
       f_{s}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

Let
\begin{align}
v &= \begin{bmatrix}
u_u \\ u_m
\end{bmatrix}
&
B &= \begin{bmatrix}
I & 0 \\
0 & I \\
0 & T \\
\end{bmatrix}
&
b &= \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 0 \\ g
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
so that
\begin{equation}
u = Bv + b
\end{equation}

Now

1. first insert $u_s$ (which by this notation is substituting $u$ from the equation above)
   \begin{equation}
   K(Bv+b) = f
   \end{equation}
2. then *symmetrize* by premultiplication by $B^T$
   \begin{equation}
   B^T K(Bv+b) = B^T f
   \end{equation}

leading to
\begin{equation}
B^T K B \:v = B^T (f - Kb)
\end{equation}
which, with a few substitutions, is the result you are looking for.

Comment: Let me comment my own answer: although $KB$ is not symmetric, I would not call premultiplication by $B^T$ a symmetrization: the point here is that KB is *not* square, so you have to reduce the number of equations in a way that is constant with the FEM formulation: $\delta u^T K u = \delta u^Tf, \forall \delta u$ becomes $\delta v^T B^T K B v = \delta v^T (\dots), \forall \delta v$: this is the real reason for premultiplying by $B^T$.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an addendum to Stefano's answer, this is known in the recent structural mechanics literature as kinematic condensation. By adding the constraint K becomes linearly dependent. You remove one equation by expresing your vector of dependent degrees of freedom $u$ as vector of independent degrees of freedom  $\nu$ using stefano's matrix $\; B$ (sometimes called $A$ in the literature: $\; A^T K A \nu = A^T f \;$).